# Getting element text value after the class has been added

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I am trying to get the text value of an element that gets a class added after being clicked on. But I cannot get it. I also tried using html().

```js
 let selectLevel;

function selectOption(menu) {

  $(menu).on('click', "li", function() {

    $(menu).find('.activeSelection').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('activeSelection');

  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  selectOption('.levelList');

  selectLevel = $('.levelList').find('.activeSelection').text();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can imagine is to trigger a custom event when you click on the list element, then bind a function to this event to update your variable.

Example below:

```js
let selectLevel;

function selectOption(menu) {

  $(menu).on('click', "li", function() {

    $(menu).find('.activeSelection').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('activeSelection');
    $(menu).trigger('itemChanged'); //trigger custom event
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  selectOption('.levelList');

  $('.levelList').on('itemChanged', function() { // wait for event on your menu
    selectLevel = $(this).find('.activeSelection').text();
    console.log(selectLevel); // just logging the current value
  });
  
});
```

```css
.activeSelection {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="levelList">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```